# Notificación IPN de pago realizado en checkout basico modo sandbox no llega

Tags: php, mercadopago

Bueno mi consulta es que no me llega la notificación IPN de pago realizado en checkout basico modo sandbox. Llegan de "merchant_order", pero no de "payment". Tengo configurada la URL en https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/ipn-notifications , con los dos cuadritos chequeados de "payment" y "merchant_order".
Sin embargo sólo me llegan notificaciónes de "merchant_order", que es cuando el comprador hace click en el link para pagar, antes de hacer el pago.

Probé de mil maneras diferentes, agregué la url "notification_url" en $preference_data, usé 2 servidores distintos para recibir la notificación, probé con modo $mp->sandbox_mode activado y desactivado, usé todas las tarjetas de sandbox para pagar (el pago se hacía correctamente), habilité recibir datos tanto de POST como GET, pero el IPN de pago realizado nunca llegó.

Supuse que sería un tema de mercadopago que para sandbox no manda IPN de "payment", pero sí en producción, así que me dispuse a hacer las pruebas fuera del sandbox, usando mi cuenta personal para pagar, y la cuenta de la página para cobrar, por una compra de 1 peso. Pero creo que los sistemas de mercadopago de alguna manera detectan que soy la misma persona y no me permite hacer el pago.

En definitiva no tengo ninguna manera de probar y por consiguiente desarrollar con las herramientas que mercadopago proporciona y no puedo avanzar...

Espero que me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Siento ser proveedor de peores noticias.. tambien mira [por que no somos soporte de...](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/por-qu%C3%A9-no-somos-soporte-al-cliente-de-tu-compa%C3%B1%C3%ADa-favorita). Esta clase de preguntas suelen eliminarse del sitio. revisa los enlaces para saber porque.

Comment: Entiendo todo lo que me comentás, pero quizás hay muchos usuarios que utilizen estos servicios y entienden el funcionamiento y pasaron por lo mismo o entienden el por qué del problema, y si bien busqué ya de antemano muchisimos resultados en google de este problema, ninguno me sirvió. Además, quise intentar hacer la pregunta ya que es sino el único medio que tengo para hacerlo.

Comment: Si, no hay problema. Solo te aclaro lo que puede pasar con la pregunta, o que reclamarle a MP por aca no lleva a nada, porque ninguno de ellos mira esto. Por ahi tenes suerte y otro usuario ve la pregunta y la contesta.. Pero aca las preguntas son sobre programacion.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta por no ajustarse al [alcance definido para el sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ni parece tratar acerca de otros temas [discutidos por la comunidad](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/161/127).

Comment: Ya me ayudó un usuario, gracias de todas formas por el aporte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto me pasó cuando hice la integración en diciembre 2016 y aparentemente sigue igual... Fijate que en la documentación ellos mismos aclaran lo siguiente:
[image: Sandbox en mantenimiento]
Podés probar la integración en producción creando usuarios y tarjetas de prueba. Revisá estos dos links que te van a servir:

1. [Crear usuarios de PRUEBA en entorno de PRODUCCIÓN](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/test/test-users/)
2. [Crear TARJETAS de PRUEBA en entorno de PRODUCCIÓN](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/test/test-payments/)

Al estar trabajando en entorno de producción, y no sandbox, vas a tener que crear dos usuarios de prueba, ya que **un comprador de prueba NO le puede pagar a un usuario real**, obviamente.

Un usuario *de prueba* actuará como **vendedor** y otro usuario *de prueba* actuará como **comprador**.

*(Es decir, en tu servidor, donde recibís la notificación, tenés que hacer la consulta del payment **usando las credenciales del usuario de prueba vendedor** y **apuntando a producción**).*

Una vez que tenés todo funcionando pipí cucú, lo único que hacés es cambiar las credenciales del usuarios de prueba vendedor, por las credenciales de tu usuario real de MP.

Cualquier cosa avisame y te doy una mano.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Esto funcionó. En mercadopago deberían corregir esa desprolijidad, y por internet son todas respuestas diferentes que no son correctas. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Genial, Agus. Me alegro mucho. En MercadoPago deberían corregir muchas cosas... Por empezar, tener algún medio oficial de contacto... Igual sí, es increíble que hace como mínimo más de un año que no funciona el sandbox... Voy a estar mirando el tag #mercadopago durante algún tiempo, a ver si aparece alguien del dev team. Saludos!

Comment: Acá hay un foro "oficial" donde hay gente de mercadopago pero tiene muy poca actividad, por si sirve: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/mercadopago-developers